# pdfTeX warning saying about duplicate figures

Tags: latex, doxygen, pdflatex

pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{figure.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored

I am using Doxygen tool to convert all my code documentation into PDF file while I am trying generating the report Finding the mentioned warning.

I have referred few suggestions online but nothing works please explain this warning and guide me to a correct path

**Edit** Albert: I've just pushed a proposed patch to github (pull request 8099, https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/8099).

Comment: Which version of doxygen and LaTeX are you using? By chance I saw this message yesterday as well, I will have to dive a little bit deeper into it...

Comment: Can you show a [mre]?

Comment: The problem comes from the patch that has been made in doxygen for the problem 
"PDF generation stops when image with caption is included in a table." (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/441). The fix is based on the https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85919/adding-a-caption-to-a-graphic-inside-a-longtable and at that moment I didn't see any problem (as far as I can reconstruct now). I have to check more, it might have to do with the with the mewest latex version (@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz do you have an idea?) after further investigations I might make an issue at texexchange.

Comment: @albert Can you make a small tex example that reproduce the problem?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I'm working on it, quick question what is the best way to include a default / example png image

Comment: @albert `example-image` should be available in most tex distributions (or `example-image-duck` if you like something fun)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I'm a bit lazy do you know the `\includegraphics` syntax by head for such an image?

Comment: @albert `\includegraphics{example-image}` should do (needs `graphic` or better `graphicx` package)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thanks that was easy.

Comment: @albert :) :D :)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I just posted the issue: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/566677/multiple-use-of-figure-number-ext4-warning

Comment: @albert unrelated to the problem, but the center environment is not a good idea, it adds additional vertical space. I would use `\centering` instead

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thanks for the tip (can you read minds?), I'm having some problems with the extra space around images (I was searching for this before I saw this ext4 problem). I quickly tried the centering but that didn't help (yet) I have to make a bit of a small problem description for that problem as well and will (when still necesssary) make an issue for it as well.

Comment: @albert extra space can also come from the `[H]` floating specifier, this does not leave tex much room for good positioning. I would always prefer `[htbp]` (no mind reading, instead https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOyvr.png)

Comment: @albert Back to the actual problem: Is there any deeper reason to use `\figcaption` also for floats that are not a longtable?

Comment: Just as starting point, you could use normal caption for floats and something else if you want to use it in your longtable: `\newcommand\figcaption[1]{
  \ifdefined\@captype
    \caption{#1}
  \else
    something else outside of floats
  \fi
}`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks I will check, tomorrow, the possibilities together with the answer to my question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/566677/multiple-use-of-figure-number-ext4-warning/566694#566694). The deeper reason is that in the table the same code is used for a figure as is done outside the the table. The code is automatically generated, I have to check whether or not I know if I'm in a table or not when putting the code of the image in the output.

Comment: Regarding the original problem: I've just pushed a proposed patch to github (pull request 8099, https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/8099).

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz the suggested `htbp` didn't give nice results as the figures "went all over the place", so I created an issue: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/566779/placing-figures-on-a-fixed-place-without-lot-of-space-around-it